# Reading from and writing to socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I've made a simple tcp server/client app where the client writes something to the server and it's then echoed back to the client. However, i'm having some problems when i'm trying to read what the server echoed back in the client.

```
string s;
while((n = read(socketFD[0],readBuf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0){
  cout<<"\nBytes read: "<<n<<endl;
  s.append(readBuf, n);
}
cout<<"\nTest after read\n";
```

I write 16 KB of text to the server. When i'm reading in the client I read 4 KB at a time.

The output from this code is:

```
Bytes read: 4096

Bytes read: 4096

Bytes read: 4096

Bytes read: 4046
```

The read call seem to block after it's done reading from the socket and never leave the loop. How can I fix this?

EDIT: This is the code in the server that handles connected clients.

```
if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
  close(listenFD);
  while ((n = read(connectFD, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0){
    cout<<"\nBytes read: "<<n<<endl;
    write(connectFD, buf, n);
  }
  cout<<"\nTest after read\n";
  exit(0);
}
```

This output is:

```
Bytes read: 4096

Bytes read: 4096

Bytes read: 4096

Bytes read: 4046

Test after read
```

What's different here compared to the code in the client? Why doesn't the read call block as it does in the client?

Comment: What's `readArr`? The loop should exit when the server closes the connection -- `read()` will return 0 to indicate EOF.

Comment: It was a typo, supposed to be readBuf

Comment: That won't work, since `readBuf` is not a C++ string or C string. C strings are required to be null-terminated, and `read` doesn't do this, since it can be used for data that isn't strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The read call seem to block after it's done reading from the socket and never leave the loop. How can I fix this?**

Short answer, don't call `read` after you're received all the data.

Write code to detect when you've received all the data you want to receive at that time and, if so, exit the loop. You have to actually implement some kind of protocol.

```
s+=readBuf;
```

That can't be right. How does it know how many bytes of data to add to `s`?

Comment: Could you check the added code in the post? Why do I get different results?

Comment: Look at the value of `n`. If it's zero, it's because the other end closed the connection. If it's `-1`, check `errno` to see why `read` returned.

Comment: So the return value 0 in read always mean the other side of the connection has been closed?

Comment: A zero from read means the inbound half of the bidirectional connection was shut down normally. If you didn't shut it down, then the other side must have. (For example, you can shut it down with the `shutdown` function.)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to either [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) if you don't want to put the read loop in another thread, that way you can see whether there's something present in the queue without actually reading from it.

Comment: On a blocking socket, a `read` call will block until either at least one byte is read or an error or connection close occurs. You can make the socket non-blocking if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from a very nice introduction to sockets in Python. It's Python, yes but it exposes the C-Socket API, so what's written there is true in your context, as well. You can read it here: http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/sockets.html

The section about 'Using Sockets' tells you exactly what the problem is you are observing. It talks about the `recv` function but that translates to your `read` function on the file descriptor.

> But if you plan to reuse your socket for further transfers, you need to realize that there is no EOT on a socket. I repeat: if a socket send or recv returns after handling 0 bytes, the connection has been broken. If the connection has not been broken, you may wait on a recv forever, because the socket will not tell you that there’s nothing more to read (for now). Now if you think about that a bit, you’ll come to realize a fundamental truth of sockets: messages must either be fixed length (yuck), or be delimited (shrug), or indicate how long they are (much better), or end by shutting down the connection. The choice is entirely yours, (but some ways are righter than others).